# Understand the Range while adding text in Google Doc using Google API in PHP

Tags: google-docs-api

I want to add text on Google Doc but confused with "range" parameter. I want to understand the role of "range" parameter while adding text to any Google Doc. I will be adding text always on top of the doc only, so please guide me where I am doing wrong. Additionally I will be adding checkboxes as well against some text too. Following is the code which I am using currently to add text and then add checkbox:

```
$requests[] = new \Google_Service_Docs_Request(
        array(
            'insertText' => array(
                'text' => 'abcdtrig',
                'location' => array(
                    'index' => 10),
            ),
        )
    );

    $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Docs_Request(
        array(
            'createParagraphBullets' => array(
                'range' => array(
                    'startIndex' => 1,
                    'endIndex' => 25
                ),
                'bulletPreset' => 'BULLET_CHECKBOX'
            ),
        )
    );

    $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Docs_Request(
        array(
            'deleteParagraphBullets' => array(
                'range' => array(
                    'startIndex' => 1,
                    'endIndex' => 2
                )
            ),
        )
    );

    $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Docs_Request(
        array(
            'insertText' => array(
                'text' => '#milk',
                'location' => array(
                    'index' => 1),
            ),
        )
    );


    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
        'requests' => $requests
    ));
```

I want it to work in a way that whenever I run this script it should add text on top of the doc and existing content of the doc will shift down.

Please help me to understand the concept of range because other things are working fine and I am clear on that. Just need to understand the "range" concept only.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Do you want to append the texts to the Google Document? Or, do you want to add the checkboxes from `Additionally I will be adding checkboxes as well`?

Comment: @Tanaike  I want to append text having checkboxes in front.   <br/>

For e.g.   <br/>

|Check box here| Text One   <br/>

|Check box here| Text Two   <br/>

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the checkbox cannot be directly put using the Google Docs API and Document service. It seems that this is the current specification. So how about reporting this as a future request to the issue tracker?